# If $f$ is additive and multiplicative, and $f$ isn't identically $0$, then prove that $x>0\Rightarrow f(x)>0$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I got this from one of Spivak's *Calculus* introductory chapters. This is the main question:

> ***17.** If $f(x)=0$ for all $x$, then $f$ satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$, and also $f(x\cdot y)=f(x)\cdot f(x)$ for all $x$ and $y$. Now suppose that $f$ satisfies these two properties, but that $f(x)$ is not always $0$. Prove that $f(x)=x$ for all $x$, as follows.

Then it guides you step-by-step into proving it. The first part asks you to prove that $f(1)=1$, and the second elaborates on this, asking you to prove that $f(x)=x$ for all rational $x$, which I did without major problems. But then it asks you to prove the following, and this is where I got stuck:

> **(c)** Prove that $f(x)>0$ if $x>0$.

And I have no idea on how to do this. Any hints or actual solutions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Suppose that $f(a)=0$ for $a\neq 0$. Then from multiplicativity:
$$
f(x)=f(a\cdot \frac xa)=f(a)f(\frac xa)=0
$$
For all $x$, contradiction. So $f(a)=0\iff a=0$. Now calculate $f(x^2)$

Answer (score 3):

If $x \ge 0$, then $f(x) = f(\sqrt{x} \sqrt{x}) = f(\sqrt{x})^2 \ge 0$ because the square of a real number is always nonnegative.

Assume that $y$ is such that $f(y) \ne 0$. Then for any $x \ne 0$ the following holds:
$$0 \ne f(y) = f(y x x^{-1}) = f(y) f(x) f(x^{-1})$$

Especially, this implies $f(x) \ne 0$ for $x \ne 0$. Therefore we have $f(x) > 0$ if $x > 0$.